# how to take a spreadsheet like table with textboxes and export to excel using jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, razor

I have a table like this, and i want to export it to excel using jquery but when i apply this table2excel plugin then my table is being exported but with the textboxes in it and takes long time to open, 
[My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsdGz.png)

how do i export the table that take the values from textboxes and exports

This is my code:

```
         <table class="table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Employee Id
                        </th>
                        <th>Cost Center</th>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.Projects)
                        {
                            <th>@Html.DisplayFor(p => item.ProjectName, new { @class = "projects" })</th>
                        }
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.Projects)
                        {
                            <th>@Html.DisplayFor(p => item.Code.CodeName, new { Style = "width:5em;" })</th>
                        }
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.Projects)
                        {
                            <th>@Html.DisplayFor(p => item.NetworkId)</th>
                        }
                        <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ForecastInfoList.Count(); i++)
                    {

                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Emp1 => Model.ForecastInfoList[i].EmpName)</td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.ForecastInfoList[i].EmpId)
                                @Html.DisplayFor(Emp1 => Model.ForecastInfoList[i].EmpSapId)
                            </td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Emp1 => Model.ForecastInfoList[i].CostCenter)</td>
                            @for (int j = 0; j < Model.ForecastInfoList[i].ProjectHours.Count(); j++)
                            {
                                <td>
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.ForecastInfoList[i].ProjectHours[j].EmpId)
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.ForecastInfoList[i].ProjectHours[j].ProjectMasterId)
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.ForecastInfoList[i].ProjectHours[j].Month)
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.ForecastInfoList[i].ProjectHours[j].Hours, new { @id = "emp"+i+ "proj"+j+"emphrs", @class = "Hours", Style = "text-align:left; width:5em;" })

                                </td>
                            }

                                <td>
                                    <div id="divtotal @(i)"></div>
                                    <span class="total_emp_value">
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.ForecastInfoList[i].EmpTotal, new { @id = "emp" + i + "emptotal" })
                                    </span>
                                </td> 
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>

                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>
                            Total
                        </th>
                        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ForecastInfoList[0].ProjectHours.Count(); i++)
                        {
                            <td>
                                <span class="total_proj_value">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.ForecastInfoList[i].ProjTotal)
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        }
                        <td>
                            <span class="grandtotal">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.ForecastInfoList[0].GrandTotal)
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
```

and the table2excel script:

```
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {

                $('#exp').on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    ResultsToTable();
                });

                function ResultsToTable() {
                    $("#example").table2excel({

                    });
                }
            });

    </script>
```

i am noob in this so please help me!

Comment: Not sure can be done with jQuery as that won't be having excel plugin, might be try from C# at server side.

Comment: okay, this table2excel is a jquery plugin to give the data out to excel